# Going from page A to B based on a condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that uses JavaScript/Ajax/PHP to login a user.  Based on the return value from the login (ie type of the user), I want to load a certain HTML page (all the pages are similar in layout but they have different contents)

I was wondering what's the right/best way to do this. Few ideas come to mind:

1. Based on the value returned, I can load .html file . So I can direct to mainpage1.html, mainpage2.html..etc
2. In the mainpage, Icould have javascript code that would check the passed in "type" and then replace the visible contents with the right contents (huge if/else condition that has all the possible HTML contents)
3. Run PHP script that would send the HTML contents from the server based on the type.

Offcourse other solutions/ways are welcome. What do you think is the right/common way to achieve this?

Comment: you need what is commonly called a router. Look for am example of a simple php router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the 3rd option,

1. if you redirect based on the type you will be misusing Ajax / not a good practice.
2. dangerous / not recommended / poor practice to do all the validations on the client side with JS.
3. Running a server side script to send the right content based on the right condition seem to be your best bet as you will have more control and more flexibility and security.

Of course i'm assuming this is very basic, i would recommend using a router on the server side to handle your routes and redirections if needed.